# HTML 5, PHP and Navigation

Tags: php, html

I'm about to start work on a new website and thought it'd be fun to use HTML5. I've decided to use the HTML5 Boilerplate project to reduce hair pulling from IE problems. In researching HTML5 I haven't see anything related to easy navigation management.

In the past I've always used PHP's include for the navigation/footer portion of websites I've created. It makes it easy to setup a new menu item or change the footer across the site. The issue I have though is that outside of the includes there is no reason for me to use PHP (usually).

So my question is do I have any other options (outside of separate menus every page) and what is the best practice? I notice a lot of websites seem to use just HTML for navigation portions of their websites, but it seems a waste of time to have to update many pages...

Am I missing something really obvious?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: You wouldn't know if they use only html for their navigations, as you can't see the php backend.

Comment: a good practice here at so is to accept the best answer as a sign of appreciation and to help other users to be able to find the best answer quicker

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use php, you can just use [frames](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_frames.asp) [oopps, better not - deprecated in HTML5], or - for only small parts like the menu - propably better [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to include external files in your html :)
Hope that helps already!

There is no big harm in using php in only small amounts though. Neither in big amounts, what I'm trying to say is that you don't loose anything if you use only a little bit of php! It's not like that you 'mess it up' just because everything else is HTML. PHP is a serverside language, that way there won't be any load on the user as well.

Comment: frames are depreciated in html5

Comment: Frames themselves are [deprecated](http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/index.html). While you _could_ use an iframe, it would probably be better to just have a small PHP file.

Comment: I have looked at frames before, but it has always seemed like a method that is frowned upon and will eventually go away. So I'd pick php include over frame/iframes I think. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Haven't used frames for so long, that I obviously missed that they are deprecated now :D Nori, yes you can just use iframes, but as I extended my question, php doesn't harm either.

Answer (score 1):

[.shtml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) is as easy as:

```
<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->
```

I haven't used it in about... 8 years, but it sounds like what you're looking for.

In my humble opinion though, I would stick with PHP. If it's the inconvenience of uploading to a server to see your changes, I'd look into a stack like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: I have no problem with PHP, its just a bother to change the files to .php for no reason other than some includes. But that is probably what I'll end up doing. I do have XAMPP and love it. PHP would be annoying without that.  :)

Comment: Hey I hear ya. Surely there are batch/bulk file renaming programs though, no?